# SFSpeechRecognizer - detect end of utterance

Tags: ios, sfspeechrecognizer

I am hacking a little project using iOS 10 built-in speech recognition. I have working results using device's microphone, my speech is recognized very accurately.

My problem is that recognition task callback is called for every available partial transcription, and I want it to **detect person stopped talking** and call the callback with `isFinal` property set to true. It is not happening - app is listening indefinitely.

Is `SFSpeechRecognizer` ever capable of detecting end of sentence?

Here's my code - it is based on example found on the Internets, it is mostly a boilerplate needed to recognize from microphone source.
I modified it by adding recognition `taskHint`. I also set `shouldReportPartialResults` to false, but it seems it has been ignored.

```
    func startRecording() {

    if recognitionTask != nil {
        recognitionTask?.cancel()
        recognitionTask = nil
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    recognitionRequest?.shouldReportPartialResults = false
    recognitionRequest?.taskHint = .search

    guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
        fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
    }

    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
        fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
    }

    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in

        var isFinal = false

        if result != nil {
            print("RECOGNIZED \(result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
            self.transcriptLabel.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
            isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
        }

        if error != nil || isFinal {
            self.state = .Idle

            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            self.recognitionRequest = nil
            self.recognitionTask = nil

            self.micButton.isEnabled = true

            self.say(text: "OK. Let me see.")
        }
    })

    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
    }

    transcriptLabel.text = "Say something, I'm listening!"

    state = .Listening
}
```

Answer (score 28):

It seems that *isFinal* flag doesn't became true when user stops talking as expected. I guess this is a wanted behaviour by Apple, because the event "User stops talking" is an undefined event.

I believe that the easiest way to achieve your goal is to do the following:

- You have to estabilish an "interval of silence". That means if the user doesn't talk for a time greater than your interval, he has stopped talking (i.e. 2 seconds).
- Create a **Timer** at the beginning of the `audio session`:

`var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "didFinishTalk", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)`

- when you get new transcriptions in `recognitionTask`invalidate and restart your timer

  `timer.invalidate()
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "didFinishTalk", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)`
- if the timer expires this means the user doesn't talk from 2 seconds. You can safely stop Audio Session and exit

Comment: Why Apple found this tuff? Only need to implement useful delegate method.

Comment: FWIW, instead of invalidating and re-creating the timer, it's possible to delay it by updating its `fireDate` property.

Comment: looks like a major fail to me.  using these scheduled timers feels like a hack

Comment: Some synchronization issue will follow along when you do it in this path. Assuming we have some internet connectivity issue either on client side or server side, it's more better to listen to an audio rather than resetting the timer on the utterance callback.

Comment: If Apple had half a brain they would expose some `seconds_silence_to_trigger_did_finish_utterance_callback` variable & internalise this timer machinery.

Comment: I am struggling to implement this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148596/implementing-user-stopped-speaking-notification-for-sfspeechrecognizer

Answer (score 4):

Based on my test on iOS10, when shouldReportPartialResults is set to false, you have to wait 60 seconds to get the result.

Comment: The max length for a recognition task is one minute, which is why it's ending for you. You can stop the task earlier though by calling `recognitionRequest.endAudio()`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a different approach that I find far more reliable in determining when the recognitionTask is done guessing: the `confidence` score.

When `shouldReportPartialResults` is set to true, the partial results will have a confidence score of `0.0`. Only the final guess will come back with a score over 0.

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in

    if let result = result {
        let confidence = result.bestTranscription.segments[0].confidence
        print(confidence)
        self.transcript = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
    }

}
```

The `segments` array above contains each word in the transcription. `0` is the safest index to examine, so I tend to use that one.

How you use it is up to you, but if all you want to do is know when the guesser is done guessing, you can just call:

`let myIsFinal = confidence > 0.0 ? true : false`

You can also look at the score (100.0 is totally confident) and group responses into groups of low -> high confidence guesses as well if that helps your application.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Speech to text in an app currently and it is working fine for me. My recognitionTask block is as follows:

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        var isFinal = false

        if let result = result, result.isFinal {
            print("Result: \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
            isFinal = result.isFinal
            completion(result.bestTranscription.formattedString, nil)
        }

        if error != nil || isFinal {
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            self.recognitionRequest = nil
            self.recognitionTask = nil
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Isn't that kind of the opposite of the question? The question is about speech recognition, this seems to cover speech synthesis.

Comment: Whoops indeed. My answer has been edited. Been working on something with speech-to-text and text-to-speech and just got confused. Read the OP's comment about a delegate and instantly thought of that.

Comment: How does `completion()` work in 2 places?

Answer (score 1):

```
if result != nil {
    self.timerDidFinishTalk.invalidate()
    self.timerDidFinishTalk = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(self.listeningTime), target: self, selector:#selector(self.didFinishTalk), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    let bestString = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString

    self.fullsTring =  bestString!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    self.st = self.fullsTring
  }
```

Here `self.listeningTime` is the time after which you want to stop after getting end of the utterance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my solution here and it works quiet nicely for me:
https://github.com/elviin/gestureai/blob/main/GestureAI/Speech/Speech2Text.swift

First detect possible sentences with the following extension:

```
extension SFTranscription {
private static let intervalBetweenSentences: TimeInterval = 1.0

var newSentenceStarted: Bool {
    let processed = Array(self.segments.reversed())
    guard processed.count > 1 else {
        return false
    }

    // print(processed.map { $0.substring }.joined(separator: " "))
    let last = processed[0]
    let previous = processed[1]

    var pause: TimeInterval = 0.0
    pause = last.timestamp - (previous.timestamp + previous.duration)
    if pause >= Self.intervalBetweenSentences, last.confidence > 0.0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var lastClosedSentence: String {
    let processed = Array(self.segments.reversed())
    var wordsInSentenceReversed: [String] = []
    guard processed.count > 1 else {
        return ""
    }

    for (index, segment) in processed.enumerated() {
        wordsInSentenceReversed.append(segment.substring)

        let isFirstSegment = index == processed.count - 1
        var pause: TimeInterval = 0.0
        if isFirstSegment == false {
            let previousIndex = index + 1 // we are in reversed array
            let previousSegment = processed[previousIndex]
            pause = segment.timestamp - previousSegment.timestamp
        }

        // Once you come to a pause, stop seatching for older words.
        if (pause >= Self.intervalBetweenSentences && segment.confidence > 0.0) || isFirstSegment {
            break
        }
    }

    return wordsInSentenceReversed.reversed().joined(separator: " ")
}
```

}

Second use the new properties in the recogniser handler:

```
    nonisolated private func recognitionHandler(audioEngine: AVAudioEngine, result: SFSpeechRecognitionResult?, error: Error?) {
    let receivedError = error != nil

    if receivedError {
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    }

    if let result, result.bestTranscription.newSentenceStarted {
        Task { @MainActor in
            transcribe(result.bestTranscription.lastClosedSentence)
        }
    }
}
```

lastClosedSentence contains segments that possibly construct together a sentence. I am using that together with LLM apis, and it works quite well as these api's require some meaningful chunks of utterance.